# Finding a commit in Git

Tags: git

ALL

I'm trying to find a commit in mt git based project.

Unfortunately running

```
git log | grep -i <some_phrase>
```

gives only the commit comment and not the SHA.

Is there some git command  can use to find a commit SHA?

TIA!!!

Comment: `git log --grep=some_phrase`

Comment: Yes, as @eftshift0 rightfully suggests, use git log's `--grep` [option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt) rather than piping to a regular `grep` command.

Comment: @eftshift0, is it possible to get a surrounding commits, i.e. the ones before and after the ones for comparison? Or I am asking too much and will just need to scroll thru git log results?

Comment: with `git log`? It doesn't ring a bell.... but who knows! But it wouldn't be that hard to ask for plain `git log` and run a search on the pager. Just write `/what-i-want` and it should take you there.... much like `less`, if you ask me. https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/.